# Finding the right stylesheet to edit in Joomla template

Tags: css, joomla

I have been trying to edit a particular style in my theme. My browser inspect shows that that the stylesheet file is local/css/template.css, i navigated to the Joomla template customize panel to edit the style sheet but the changes i made is not reflecting. please help

Answer (score 0):

View template.css in your web browser to check if you can see the change. You may need to clear the Joomla cache and any other caching (e.g. via your hosting control panel or your CDN control panel etc) before you see the latest version of the CSS file.

Alternatively, this may be a [specificity](https://designshack.net/articles/css/what-the-heck-is-css-specificity) issue.